# Timer_Tick con variables Globales o publicas en diferentes Ventanas

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en mi interface de mensajes
Para poder listar los mensajes lo hago mediante el evento `loadmsj` la cual solo requiere dos variables que son ***usr_log*** y ***usr_dos***
Me iba perfecto hasta que probe abrir en otra ventana tal vez no lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta
En el evento load tengo algo como esto

```
//Variables globales declaradas al inicio
public static string usr_log;
public static string usr_dos;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Agrupa los mensajes de acuerdo al usuario logueado y lo guarda en repeater
    tabla_msj001 = o_msj001._05(cod_usuario);
    rpt_lista_mensaje.DataSource = tab_msj001;
    rpt_lista_mensaje.DataBind();

    usr_log = tab_msj001.Rows[0]["va_usr_log"].ToString();
    usr_dos = tab_msj001.Rows[0]["va_usr_dos"].ToString();

    //Selecciona el primer dato y muestra sus respectivos mensajes También en otro Repeater
    //(ESTO MUESTRA LOS MENSAJES QUE TIENE EL USUARIO LOGUEADO CON EL OTRO USUARIO)
    loadmsj(cod_usuario, tab_msj001.Rows[0]["va_usr_dos"].ToString());
}
```

Para mostrar mensajes en tiempo real utilizo un `Timer_Tick` a esto les paso variables globales que guardo tanto al inicio como al momento de seleccionar otro mensaje

```
protected void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  loadmsj(usr_log,usr_dos);
}
```

El problema es que al momento de abrir la **ventan2**  el cuadro de mensajes se carga el mismo mensaje que tengo abierto en **ventana1** y si selecciono otro mensaje en **ventana2** tambien se cambia en **ventana2** como dije al inicio tal vez no es la manera correcta

**alguna sugerencia??**

Answer (score 0):

cuando abras la ventana ábrela de esta manera

```
ventana2 v2 = new ventana2();
AddOwnedForm(v2);//con esto aclaramos que es el formulario padre
ventana2.ShowDialog();//show();
this.close();
```

ahora para regresar al formulario padres desde el hijo

```
ventana1 v1 = owner as  ventana1();
ventana1.ShowDialog();//show();
this.close();
```

prueba con eso debería funcionar ya que no reiniciaras el evento load del formulario

Comment: Eduardo no manejo ventanas padre ni abro la ventana2 con un boton, solo copio el link de mensajes.aspx lo pego en otra pestaña y ambas tiene el mismo mensaje a causa de que el 'Timer_Tick' utiliza las variables publicas y sucederia lo mismo si tuviera 3 o 4 pestañas abiertas con el formulario mensajes.aspx